# How to remove retained apk on production track on google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I accidentally retain unstable version of apk on production when publish the latest stable version. so now I have stable version(30) and unstable version(29) on production track.

My question is, how do i remove that retain apk(29)?

[image]

Comment: Did you find the way to remove retained APK?

Comment: The only method is base on my answer below. Weird but that how it work. I am not sure if it still working but you can give a try. @Fisher

Comment: If it still work, please mark it as an answer to help others. @Fisher

Comment: I've seen your answer for years but can't find the exact way to fix this issue. Recently I also contacted the googleplay-developer-support@google.com and got the solution. It need notice the 3-dot menu to find "Remove APK" function for the retained APK when releasing a new version.
If you attached a screenshot in Play console to make the steps clear, I will be glad to confirm your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I contact google developer and they said the only way to remove that retain version is by uploading new version of the apk on the production track. Then you can choose to remove all previous version of apk(30,29).